# Can I Destructively Alter My Database in a Django View?

Tags: django, database, templates, view

So I'm loading up my queryset to send to my template. One of the objects is incident.

Now, each incident has a bunch of attributes like "status" and "employee", so in my template I can just do

```
// incident.html //

{% for incident in incidents %}
  <h1> {{ incident.employee }} - {{ incident.status }} </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, for convenience I want to add new properties that didn't exist before to incident, like "mood" or whatever, I can add

```
// views.py //

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
  ...
  for incident in incidents:
        incident.mood = "scary"
```

And then in my template I can just access incident.mood along with incident.status and incident.employee.

```
// incident.html //

{% for incident in incidents %}
  <h1> {{ incident.employee }} - {{ incident.status }} </h1>
  <h3>  It was very {{ incident.mood }} </h3>
{% endfor %}
```

So, what I want to know is, is it possible to mess up and destructively alter the database if I'm not careful here? If I add

```
// views.py //

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
  ...
  for incident in incidents:
    incident.employee = "Daffy Duck"
```

Am I going to ruin all of my data and permanently make the name of the employee "Donald Duck" in every one of my incidents?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these changes will be made in your database as long as you don't use `.update()` to make changes or call `.save()` after you have made changes. Otherwise the changes are just stored in memory and therefore not permanent.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a lot less scared about that upcoming production merge now.